# C# IRC client not sending data (it seems)

Tags: c#, .net, client, irc

A friend and I are working on an `IRC` client in C#, just for practice.

We've implemented it so that it listens for data all the time on a separate thread, even though I don't believe that this should interfere in any way.

We have a `IRCClient` class that uses the following Send method, which, apparently doesn't work.

```
public void Send(string command)
{
    NetworkStream stream = this.client.GetStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

    writer.Write(command + "\r\n");
    writer.Flush();
}
```

The "client" attribute is a `TcpClient` that is properly connected to the IRC server. And yes, we can receive data.

Comment: What is your question ? Am I missing anything ?

Comment: As AB Kolan pointed out, there's not sufficient context here for us to give any specific answers.

Comment: any full source code with solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the IRC client (in order to send commands) must exclude the preceding slash "/". So instead of "/say hello", you just have to send "SAY hello".

Answer (score 3):

You can use Wireshark ( http://www.wireshark.org/ ) in order to check the raw data you send and receive. It has support for IRC protocol and it will help you a lot with debugging your client.